# What does sorted by "faq" mean?

Tags: support

What is the sort criterion used to generate [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=faq)? The questions are not sorted by views, nor votes, nor number of answers. So by what?

#### Edit

I guess I never hovered long enough to see the tooltip. Now that it is explained by rm -rf, I must say I think it's a bad name. Why not just call it "most linked"?

Comment: This was brought up on [metase] several times, but Jeff Atwood was adamant in not changing it. Requesting it again is probably a lost cause, but I remain hopeful that someone in SE might see the light now, since he no longer works there.

Answer (score 1):

The mouseover says "questions with the most links". The next question is therefore "what does 'questions with the most links' mean?".

Comment: Those are questions that are linked to the most (i.e., in other posts on this site or outside this site). The theory being that if something is linked to very often, then it is something that's frequently asked.